# Mismatched input error when creating Athena table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Getting the following error,

```
line 1:8: mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting: 'OR', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW'
```

when creating an Athena table with the following command,

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'abcd_123' (Item:struct<Id:struct<S:string>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('ignore.malformed.json' = 'true')
LOCATION 's3://mybucket'
```

I've gone through other Q&A's and none of the answers have helped me - any points as to where the error might be here ?

Comment: How do you execute it? query looks just fine.

Comment: Try running crawler on that s3 bucket location to populate table structure rather creating it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a space between Item and struct instead of a colon, like so

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'abcd_123' (
    Item struct<
        Id:struct<
            S:string
        >
    >
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('ignore.malformed.json' = 'true')
LOCATION 's3://mybucket'
```

This is taken from [the AWS Athena docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/creating-tables.html). I believe the colon is only required between fields of structs and their types, not column names and their types.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cloudfront_logs (
    `Date` Date,
    Time STRING,
    Location STRING,
    Bytes INT,
    RequestIP STRING,
    ...
```